# SetPartitions from Mathematica to Python

Tags: python, sorting, wolfram-mathematica, partitioning

I have an ordered set partitioning function in Mathematica, just like:

```
SetPartitions[Table[i, {i, 2, 5}]]
```

. The output of the above code is:`{{{2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 4, 5}, {3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5}}, {{2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 3, 5}, {4}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, {{2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{2, 3}, {4}, {5}}, {{2, 4}, {3}, {5}}, {{2, 5}, {3}, {4}}, {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}}`
. And I want to have exactly the same output like this in Python. I know there are many set partition questions asked here, but, none could give the exact same ordering as in Mathematica. The generalization of this is something like

```
SetPartitions[Table[i, {i, a, b}]]
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this ordering?

Comment: There is [more_itertools.set_partitions](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.set_partitions)

Comment: As far as I understood, It seems Mathematica puts the first list with the lowest starting number i.e {2..} first. Then, with the same logic, it goes on with other list elements.

Comment: Also Python code here: [Equivalence Classes and Set Partitions by E.P. Adorio](http://www.geocities.ws/eadorio/equiv.pdf)

Comment: It seems the sorting algorithm in Mathematica has a slightly different ordering than in Python.